# Prove that a boolean function using only $\vee$ and $\wedge$ must attain the value $1$ at least once

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Please give me feedback on this

Prove that a boolean function constructed only by using $\vee$
 and $\wedge$
 (without using $\sim$
 ) must attain the value $1$ at least once.

Comment: What does this mean: "at least once"?

Comment: Consider $f(1,1,\cdots,1)$

Comment: The function $x\wedge 0$  has value $0$ for all $x$, showing that the result is not true if _constants_ are allowed in the expression for the Boolean function.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Every Boolean function $f$ in $n$ Boolean variables is defined by a propositional formula $\tau_f$ in $n$ propositional variables. Prove by induction on the complexity of $\tau_f$ that $f(1,\ldots,1)=1$ for every Boolean function $f$ such that $\tau_f$ is constructed using only the Boolean connectives $\land$ and $\lor$. Use the recursive construction of such formulas: the individual propositional variables are the basic ones, and if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are propositional formulas constructed using only $\land$ and $\lor$, so are $\sigma\land\tau$ and $\sigma\lor\tau$.